# trigonometric identies, $\sin(z)=i$, complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm stuck with trying to calculate $\sin(z) = i$. How do you proceed with such questions, I did the $e^{iz}...$ etc for $\sin(z)$ and get to the point: $t^2 + 2t -1 = 0$, where do I go from here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition,
$$
\sin z=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}
$$
so your equation becomes
$$
e^{iz}-e^{-iz}=-2
$$
and so
$$
e^{2iz}+2e^{iz}-1=0
$$
Solve the quadratic $t^2+2t-1=0$ and then $e^{iz}=t$.

The roots of the quadratic are $-1+\sqrt{2}$ and $-1-\sqrt{2}$.

Let's look at $e^{iz}=\sqrt{2}-1$; writing $z=x+iy$, we get
$$
e^{-y}e^{ix}=\sqrt{2}-1
$$
so $x=2k\pi$ and $e^{-y}=\sqrt{2}-1$; therefore we get the family of solutions
$$
z=2k\pi-i\log(\sqrt{2}-1)
$$

Recall that a nonzero complex number can uniquely be written as $z=ru$, where $|u|=1$ and $r>0$; here $u=1$.

In the case of $-\sqrt{2}-1$, we have to solve
$$
e^{-y}e^{ix}=(\sqrt{2}+1)(-1)
$$
so we get $e^{-y}=\sqrt{2}+1$ and $e^{ix}=-1$, leading to the family of solutions
$$
\pi+2k\pi-i\log(\sqrt{2}+1)
$$
(With $\log$ I mean the natural logarithm, that you may be writing $\ln$).

Answer (score 3):

Hint : $z = x+yi$ where $x, y\in \mathbb{R}$

$\sin z = \sin(x+yi) = \sin x \cosh y + i\cos x \sinh y$

because $\cos iy =\cosh y$ and $\sin iy = i\sinh y$

Now equate real and complex parts to solve $\sin z = i$

Comment: Thats not how I thought I was gonna solve it...

Comment: @A.Maine But don't you find this a really quick and direct solution?

Comment: I thought I should rewrite sin(z) as e^(iz) -... get t^2 +2t -1 = 0, solve that one, and then some way get it out, but I cant make it right, isnt is possible to do it the way I do it?

Answer (score 2):

The other answer already addresses your question, and now I try a different approach perhaps a little closer to yours:

$$i=\sin z=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}=\frac{e^{2iz}-1}{2ie^{iz}}\implies e^{2iz}-1=-2e^{iz}\implies$$

$$e^{2iz}+2e^{iz}-1=0\implies e^{iz}_{1,2}=\frac{-2\pm2\sqrt2}2=-1\pm\sqrt2\implies$$

$$z=-i\text{ Log}\,(-1\pm\sqrt2)=-i\log\left|\,-1\pm\sqrt2\,\right|+2k\pi$$

Observe that the inverse hyperbolic function $\mathrm{arcsinh}$ appears there, since

$$\mathrm{arcsinh}z=\text{ Log}\,\left(z+\sqrt{1+z^2}\right)\;,\;\;$$

and we get two infinite sets of solutions:

$$z=\begin{cases}2k\pi+i\,\mathrm{arcsinh}(-1)\\{}\\2k\pi-i\,\mathrm{arcsinh}(-1)\end{cases}$$

Since we have both signs on the imaginary parts, we can as well simply write there $\mathrm{arcsinh}(1)$

Comment: $\arcsin h(1)$?

Comment: @egreg $\mathrm{sinh}^{-1}$, or $\mathrm{arcsinh}$, or $\mathrm{asinh}$, or $\mathrm{argsh}$. The notation varies...

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I know; I wanted to point out that $\arcsin h(1)$ is meaningless.

Comment: @egreg I know you know :-) LaTeX is just annoying, sometimes: some functions are "defined", others need *\mathrm*, and sometimes even those who are defined do not comply with your own notation. I love handwriting!

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Agree with you: sometimes MathJaX here just sucks.

Comment: @DonAntonio `\operatorname{arsinh}(1)` is not that difficult `;-)`

Comment: z=−i Log(−1±2–√)=−ilog|−1±2–√|+2kπ, im supposed to have one more solution at this

Comment: @egreg For me it is very cumbersome to write all that, in particular if one has to do that more than 2-3 times.

Comment: @A.Maine I don't understand : what "one more solution to this" do you mean?